# Understanding CORS handling for external service in Angular2

Tags: angular

I came across one scenario where I am trying to fetch data from external URL ('http://knowstack.com/webtech/charts_demo/data.json')

In case of Angular2, I am getting CORS error. As per my understanding, CORS need to enable on service side and not in Angular2 application.

But I do not have access service side. Hence, this can’t be done.

Now, if I change my front end from Angular2 to ASP.NET MVC core UI and use httpClient class of System.Net.Http namespace. I do get a response and data back.

I am wondering how this is working in ASP.NET MVC core UI and Angular2 front-end gives me CORS error. **How to overcome this external service CORS scenario in Angular2?**

Below are my 2 cases along with code-

> **Case 1: Angular2**

In this, I am using Angular2 version RC4 with npm version 3.9.6, node version 4.4.7. Browser chrome, Editor: VScode

To execute application, I am simply using ‘npm start’ command.

```
        this._http.get('http://knowstack.com/webtech/charts_demo/data.json')
                .map(this.extractData)
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    this.options11 = {
                                    title : { text : 'knowstack' },
                                    series : [{
                                        name : 'knowstack',
                                        data : response.json()
                                    }]
                                };
                },
                (error) => { 
                    this.errorMessage = <any>error
                });
```

**Error in browser console:**

[image: Error]

> **Case 2: ASP.NET MVC core 1.0, Browser chrome, IDE: VS community 2015**

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
           string GET_DATA_URL = "http://knowstack.com/webtech/charts_demo/data.json";

            HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient();
            client1.BaseAddress = new Uri(GET_DATA_URL);

            client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response1 = client1.GetAsync(GET_DATA_URL).Result;

            if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var dataObjects = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(dataObjects);

            }
            else
            {
                // handle failure response
            }
        return View();
    }
```

Please let me know if you need any information from my side.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the ASP.NET code is executed on your server and the server then returns the HTML to you.

CORS is a technology that is build into the browser. The browser prevents websites to make AJAX calls to foreign websites that don't allow access from outside. Because in the case of ASP.NET this request is done by your backend. Because for the backend this is a normal HTTP request (like you do with your browser) it doesn't need to check for CORS. Because of this the request also doesn't send the "origin" header. CORS is only there to prevent AJAX calls from foreign hosts.

What you can do to make this work in Angular2 is to create a proxy on your domain that just bypasses the request to the external service and acts like the request happens to your site so CORS isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please give some pointers on how I create a proxy on my domain?

Comment: What webserver are you using? Apache? nginx?

Comment: For development, I am using lite-server as shown in angular2 quickstart tutorial.

Comment: ok, I don't know how to use this lite-server, but here is an GitHub issue addressing the proxy problem: https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/61 maybe that helps